# Log in to Facebook with PHP - Broken official documentation

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok I need help to understand the login with facebook in PHP, in the official [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/) we have the following:

**login.php**

```
fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://example.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

**fb-callback.php**

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('{app-id}'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
```

I have no problem with the above, but in the last line of `fb-callback.php` mention that we can redirect to the `members.php` page but then.

**1.-** What do I have to put on the `members.php` page so that it is safe and can only be seen by the users who started the session?

**2.-** All the pages that you want to protect (as in point 1) must make a request to facebook on each visit? That is, is there any method of just logging in once and then storing the information in sessions or something like that, without risk of someone getting in the middle?

I hope you can help me understand this, I'm in a school project and I need a way to authenticate users securely, I know that framework exists (like symfony) but there are thousands of lines, I just want to protect a page from the view "publish ", does it really have to be so difficult?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: 1. Put _something_ into the session that indicates the user successfully authenticated via Facebook. `$_SESSION['has_successfully_authenticated_ via_facebook'] = true;` Check for that value being set/true on your "protected" pages. 2. No, that's what you got your session for.

Comment: @CBroe I do not understand, you could help me with an example code, which would be the correct use for members.php I also have the doubt since you put "protected" in quotes, that is, this is not a good method to protect pages? Thank you!